# Intuitive meaning of dy/dx

Tags: calculus

How can I explain to someone who is a beginner, the basic idea and intuition behind dy/dx? I'm introducing calculus to one of my friends and here are the questions I might encounter:
Why dy/dx?
What do I even need to find the slope?
How does that relate to rate of change of y with respect to x?
What could be some real life examples for a better understanding?
What information does the slope at every point of a curve, which is just a line, give me?

I'd like to explain all of this giving an intuitive sense to the formal differential calculus. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that you are using cartesian coordinates to plot the function $f(x)$. Thus, what you are "measuring" is the rate of change of function $f$, i.e. $\dfrac {f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}$.

Comment: If you have an afternoon, you could take a look at [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr).

Comment: These are all valid questions but not for someone who is attempting to explain Calculus. Your friend would be better served by someone who has mastered the basics.

Comment: start with linear functions, consider $y=x$, $y=2x$, $y=-x$, $y=2$. Show what happens to value of $y$ if $x$ is increased by $dx$.

Comment: It's the limit of $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ as $\Delta x\to 0.$